# Sending a SOAP request using Postman

Tags: post, soap, postman, http-post

I'm trying to send a SOAP request to the Loqate services following their API documentation found [here](https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/apis/Capture/Interactive/Find/1.1/).

The documentation says the SOAP end point is

> https://api.addressy.com/Capture/Interactive/Find/v1.1/wsdlnew.ws

and the sample request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Find
            xmlns="http://api.addressy.com/">
            <Key>AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11</Key>
            <Text>wr5 3da</Text>
            <IsMiddleware>True</IsMiddleware>
            <Container>GB|RM|ENG|3DA-WR5</Container>
            <Origin>52.182,-2.222</Origin>
            <Countries>GB,US,CA</Countries>
            <Limit>10</Limit>
            <Language />
            <Bias />
            <Filters />
            <GeoFence />
        </Find>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I load up Postman and make these steps, following the Postman guide from their [blog](https://blog.postman.com/postman-makes-soap-requests-too/).

When I send the request, I just get back [this page](https://api.addressy.com/Capture/Interactive/Find/v1.1/wsdlnew.ws) . I'm not sure why it's not working.

[image]

How can I make a SOAP request to this API? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the service endpoint, it's an address where you can get the WSDL. Inside that WSDL you will find the service endpoint:

```
<soap:address location="http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/Capture/Interactive/Find/v1.10/soapnew.ws"/>
```

Send your request there. The endpoint is over http, but the https seems to be working on the same address: https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/Capture/Interactive/Find/v1.10/soapnew.ws

One other thing. If you want a more specific client than Postman, you could try [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/).

Comment: Thank you I thought it was something silly. Code brain after so many hours of bashing my head xd

Answer (score 0):

You would try to use CDATA within soap body, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Find xmlns="http://api.addressy.com/">
            <![CDATA[
                <Key>AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11</Key>
                <Text>wr5 3da</Text>
                <IsMiddleware>True</IsMiddleware>
                <Container>GB|RM|ENG|3DA-WR5</Container>
                <Origin>52.182,-2.222</Origin>
                <Countries>GB,US,CA</Countries>
                <Limit>10</Limit>
                <Language />
                <Bias />
                <Filters />
                <GeoFence />
            ]]>                     
        </Find>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata/